# Context menu to add column not working when defining columns property to hide some columns

Tags: handsontable

I needed a way to create a spreadsheet where user can potentially paste in any no of columns. Currently pasting things in the spreadsheet does not work as mentioned here https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/553, so I wanted to enable the context menu to add column. This works fine when you have plain array as data source and you are not setting the columns property, but if you do need to define the columns attribute then things dont work when setting the

```
contextMenu: ['col_right']
```

. I needed to define the columns property because I need to hide certain columns (as mentioned here https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/120).
The only way to make things work would be to define custom action for context menu, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Here is a jsbin : http://jsfiddle.net/8V4Z5/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok one work around that worked for me requires playing bit with the data structure. Seeing that I could only make context menu work when data source is plain array and "columns" property should not be defined , I had to provide plain array as data source. Example like:

```
var actualData = [
    {"spreadSheetData":[ "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"]},
    {"year":"2008", "spreadSheetData":[10, 11, 12, 13]},
    {"year":"2009", "spreadSheetData":[ 20, 11, 14, 13]},
    {"year":"2010", "spreadSheetData":[30, 15, 12, 13]}
];

var data = [];
actualData.forEach(function(d){
    data.push(d.spreadSheetData);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw3WE/

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you initialize a Handsontable with the columns option, you can no longer use the context menu to add a column.

A solution is to use the cell option instead.
To solve your issue, I replaced...

```
columns: [{
  data: 1
}, {
  data: 2
}, {
  data: 3
}],
```

...with...

```
cells: function (row, col, prop) {
  var cellProperties = {};

  cellProperties.data = col;

  return cellProperties;
},
```

Here's the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oyxv3g9w/

Note that I also commented out a callback in the fiddle because the way it was implemented, it prevented the new column from being created despite the context menu item wasn't greyed out anymore.